# How to give breakline in html table.?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Image of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/517Hh.png)I have designed table with horizontal and vertical scroll bar. Now problem here is in same scrollable there are two tables with same data but i want to give break line after completing the first table data. How to give break line. Here intention is i have to show more than two responsive bordered tables with scrollable. I have tried this code but i am not getting break line.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
</style>
</head>
<body>



<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
  <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why not using two tables?

Comment: Yeps, close the first table, add a line break and start a new table. Another (ugly) option is to create an invisible row in the table.

Comment: Data is huge so. I want show vertical and horizontal scrollable. There are more than 4 separate tables so i need show in scrollable format.

Comment: @Tal i did same but scrollable went of. I need to show all the tables in scrollable.

Comment: just wrap each table in a div. Easier for thw future too, maybe you want to make them collapseble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand exactly what you're trying to do, but it sounds like maybe you want to use `colspan` to create a single cell that fills the width of your table, so you can leave it blank, like so:

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="12"></td>
</tr>
```

You can then add a class to this blank row to style it how you want, e.g.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px; 
}

th:first-child, td:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}    
th:last-child, td:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid black; 
}
tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
.divider td {
  background: black;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>



<div style="overflow:auto;">
  <table>
    <tr class="divider">
      <td colspan="12">Heading</td>
    </tr>  
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="divider">
      <td colspan="12">Heading</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="divider">
      <td colspan="12">Heading</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have attached the image above. according to that i have to design table. please help

Comment: That's how I'd do it.

Comment: But i am unable to give header for each table. and line break is also small.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand but I've updated the code snippet, is that closer to what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes. Its too near.

Comment: But line break is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll("tr");
var index = 0;
 for( index=0; index < x.length; index = index + 4) {
      x[index].style.borderTop= '5px solid red'
 }
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
```

```html
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
  <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to give break line for second table and third table. ex: in same scrollable window three tables must display separately with separate header menu for all the tables.